# Facebook - App access token empty data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using my app access token to get some informations of the user. I want to get the events of a user.

When i try with a user token with the user_events permission and this request I get the events :

```
GET /v2.8/Id/events?fields=id,name&since=2017-02-23
```

however, I have to use my app token and the user_events permission. 
So I am trying this but get an empty data [] with (using app token)

```
GET /v2.8/ID/events?fields=id&since=2017-02-23
```

So my question is : 
do I have to put as ID the id i can find from this http://findmyfbid.com or the id facebook I have in my database when I used the identification of facebook ?

Second question is : 
why is my data empty with the app token ?

Comment: You can not get a user’s events with your app access token, you need to use the user access token. (And when you use the user token, you don’t need to app-scoped user id, but can simply use `me` instead - `/me/events`)

Comment: Thank you ! Ok I use the same token i use for the connection ? How must I add it in the url request ?

Comment: As an additional GET parameter named `access_token`.